# Moderator History not logging actions correctly

Tags: bug, moderator-tools

Whilst flicking through the moderator history pages on Bio I noticed something a little quirky.

It's related to this question:

- [asked Feb 27 at 5:51](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1212/how-do-anti-porn-anti-prostitution-anti-gay-and-xenophobic-traits-reproduce)
- closed as not constructive by Mad Scientist♦ Feb 27 at 6:36
- deleted by Rory M♦ Mar 3 at 12:29

Yet in the moderator history pages for myself and Mad Scientist respectively, the logs show that it was Mad Scientist who deleted the question as well as closing it. I have an entry for deleting flags from the post, yet in the flag history page the two flags were actually deleted by Mad Sci.

Did they get swapped round?

---

And actually something similar has just happened on this question:

- [asked Apr 6 at 8:40](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1682/why-circadian-rhythm-is-important)
- closed as exact duplicate by Mad Scientist♦ Apr 6 at 9:00
- deleted by Rory M♦ 9 secs ago

I get another lot of deleted flags (no flag history on this question) and even more interestingly Mad Scientist has no history at all for the post, not even the veto close.  Confused face!

Comment: It's a conspiracy!!

Comment: On hovering over the entry for Feb 27 in my mod history it says that you deleted it. It just seems to be a bit of an unintuitive way of grouping the actions together. The "delete flag votes" on your history is a bit strange, that should say deleted post.

Comment: @Fabian everything deletes flag votes. Every freaking action I take "deletes flag votes". I was wondering why that shows up, it doesn't show post deletions either best I can tell